# Is there any solution to get resolved items?

Tags: 2013

we have created a .NET assembly containing a Custom Resolver (implemented the IResolver interface) , installed it in the GAC on all CM and Publisher servers, and updated  /config/Tridion.ContentManager.config

```
<add itemType="Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Component">
  <resolvers>
    <add type="Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Resolving.ComponentResolver" assembly="Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing, Version=6.1.0.0996, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=360aac4d3354074b" />
    <add type="Example.Resolving.ComponentResolver" assembly="Example.Resolving, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=239a69fd0ef6bf5d" />
  </resolvers>
</add>
```

My Class:

```cs
public void Resolve(IdentifiableObject item, ResolveInstruction instruction, PublishContext context, Tridion.Collections.ISet<ResolvedItem> resolvedItems)
{
}
```

we have getting resolvedItems as a null.
Is there any solution to get resolved items?

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure there is a hotfix for this, but for some reason can't find it right now. The default resolving behavior was (wrongly) changed in 2013, and by default it is not resolving dependencies correctly (with the result of what you're seeing).

I'll try to find the hotfix for this and update the answer when I find it...

**Update** I *think* it's hotfix CME_2013.1.0.87280 - the publish instruction created by the CME does not specify to resolve component links, so dependencies are not calculated.